Load map tile in ArcMap from Online image links
The problem:

I have many image links as tile maps which are in equal dimension and related data content.
They are stored online and they will change by time
They are presentable in different zoom levels.
I want to display them as combined tiled map service which will load directly from online source link in ArcMap.
Basically their links are not the same in format (address) and may differ in comparison with together.

I have no idea about how to do it. But I think an empty *.mbtile file which loads its content from image links, can help.
Do you have any idea?
(Please explain like I am 5!)
